# What do the guidelines of ancient scriptures say on "resource wastage"?

Tags: scripture, food, research

In today's time, the "wastage" is among the grave issues. For example **wasting food/water** etc.. e.g. nations like USA alone consume 25% of world resources, despite having 5% population.

Do the scriptures have any mention of such "wasteful behaviour"?
<sub>(Mention in form of guidelines or punishment or anything else)</sub>

Comment: This would fall under the general category of greed. But other than that, there would be no reference.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, "wasting" is related more with "negligence", rather than "greed".

Comment: Resource, food, water etc are god given. Probably some scriptures may have cited the subject mentioned. Hence the question may leave opened.

Answer (score 3):

**`resource-wastage in scriptures`**

Food Wastage -: Here The [**Taittiriya Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79856.html)  treats Food being the first gateway to the knowledge of Brahman, the śruti enjoins the contemplation of Brahman through the symbol of food. And advices us not to neglect /waste / abandon food.

> Anuvaka VII
>
> अन्नंन निन्द्यात् |  तद्व्रतं |  प्राणो वा अन्नम् । शरीरमन्नादम् ।
>   प्राणे शरीरं 
> प्रतिष्ठितम् । शरीरे प्राणः प्रतिष्ठितः ।
>   तदेतदन्नमन्ने प्रतिष्ठितम् ॥ २ ॥
>
> **Annnm na Nindyaat |** prāṇo vā annam | śarīramannādam | prāṇe śarīraṃ 
>   
> pratiṣṭhitam | śarīre prāṇaḥ pratiṣṭhitaḥ | tadetadannamanne
>   pratiṣṭhitam || 2 ||
>
> Do not disrespect the food
>
> Anuvaka VIII
>
> अन्नं न परिचक्षीत । तद् व्रतम् ॥ १ ॥
>
> 1. **He shall not abandon food**; that his vow. This vow is enjoined on him who contemplates life and the body as taught above.
>
> That his vow: This, as before, is intended to extol food: when **thus
>   one does not abandon food, without making any such distinction as good
>   food and bad food,** food becomes exalted. The same interpretation
>   should be put on the succeeding passages also, beginning with “Water
>   verily is food.”

---

Further more [**Manu smiriti**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200766.html) tells us to use our wealth with care and wisely and one should conserve it . Indirectly advising us not to overspend it.

> अलब्धं चैव लिप्सेत लब्धं रक्षेत् प्रयत्नतः । 
>  रक्षितं वर्धयेच्चैव
>   वृद्धं पात्रेषु निक्षिपेत् ॥ ९९ ॥
>
> alabdhaṃ caiva lipseta labdhaṃ rakṣet prayatnataḥ | 
>  rakṣitaṃ
>   vardhayeccaiva vṛddhaṃ pātreṣu nikṣipet || 99 ||
>
> He shall strive to obtain what has not been obtained; what he has
>   gained he shall preserve with care; he shall augment what has been
>   preserved and what has been augmented he shall bestow upon suitable
>   recipients—(99) See the Artha Shashtra commentary
>
> Arthaśāstra (p. 32)—‘The science of Government tends to the acquiring
>   of what has not been acquired, to the saving of what has been
>   acquired, to the augmentation of what has been saved and to the
>   spending of the augmented in proper places.

There is a interesting story in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana** where mother earth hides the resources inside her just because some people were over utilizing / misusing them.

> पुरा सृष्ट्य: ह्योषधयो ब्रह्मणा या विशाम्पते | 
>  भुज्यमाना  मया
>   दृष्टा असद्भिधृतव्रतै ||6||
>
> purā sṛṣṭā hy oṣadhayo brahmaṇā yā viśāmpate 
>  bhujyamānā mayā
>   dṛṣṭā asadbhir adhṛta-vrataiḥ
>
> My dear King, the seeds, roots, herbs and grains, which were created
>   by Lord Brahmā in the past, are now being used by nondevotees, who are
>   devoid of all spiritual understanding.[**SB 4.18.6**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/18/6)
>
> ---
>
> अपालितानाद्रुता च भवद्भिर्लोकपालकै: |
>  चोरीभूतेsथ लोकेsहं
>   यज्ञार्थेsग्रसमोषधी: ||7||
>
> apālitānādṛtā ca bhavadbhir loka-pālakaiḥ corī-bhūte ’tha loke ’haṁ
>   yajñārthe ’grasam oṣadhīḥ
>
> My dear King, not only are grains and herbs being used by nondevotees,
>   but, as far as I am concerned, I am not being properly maintained.
>   Indeed, I am being neglected by kings who are not punishing these
>   rascals who have turned into thieves by using grains for sense
>   gratification. Consequently I have hidden all these seeds, which were
>   meant for the performance of sacrifice.[**SB 4.18.7**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/18/7)
>
> ---
>
> **purport**
>
> Although there are immense potencies within the earth for the
>   production of grains, fruits and flowers, this production is checked
>   by the earth itself when it is misused by nondevotees, who have no
>   spiritual goals.

**Moral of the above  Story:**
Food is not just something that we eat to satisfy hunger or satisfy our tastes. It is a gift from Bhagavān. Food is precious and holy. We should see food as a means of doing worship and for doing good karma.
We should take care of mother earth while growing food on her. We should not abuse or over-use our natural resources. Rather, we should conserve them as much as we can.

You can read the whole  story  [**SB 4.17**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/17)  & 18

Comment: Nice answer. Would suggest to remove the Gita part as that's a translation mistake & not related to wasting. Use [gita-supersite](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=12&etgb=1&choose=1) instead.

Comment: Ok , Thanks  - BTW  I  tried to find about wastage of water in scriptures but i think the scriptures are not much talking about this issue , there is only a story in puranas where bathing directly in pond is prohibited.Will add more references as i will find them.

Comment: I think the meaning of BG 3.12 is very broad and I think it could be used to answer this question also. I will update the answer and will add some explanation about that after searching. :)

Comment: The verse says, that *Deva*-s, i.e. the elements of nature and animals including humans were created at the beginning of creation. The creatures were supposed to work (*yajna*) and serve the nature. In its response, the nature (in form of various demigods) fulfills various necessities. Those who don't participate in this cycle, are *like* thieves. Now, this verse may not easily be relate-able to "wastage". :-)

Comment: **Annam na Nindyaat** means one should not abandon food or one should not criticize food? Whose translation are u using?  NindA means criticism.

Comment: "परिचक्षीत" Parichakshit is the word used for abandoning food , but  I used the Nindya  just to show that we should disrespect food , in broad sense by avoiding if given and thus wasting .

Comment: Sorry please read Shouldn't  instead of should.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Ok then u highlighted the wrong sanskrit verse.. BTW does not Parichaksha mean to reject?

Comment: No i think both are important  because disrespecting food is first step in wasting it and since its a Upanishads quote , its very deep. Lots of acharyas drawn different meanings. But in general non vedanta view , this whole chapter can be used to give such a type of answers. Like proper utilization  of resources  most notable the food .:)